# calculate method execution time in Visual Studio Express (No profiler available)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio Express Edition and it don't have any profiler or code analyzer.

Code having two delegate performing same task, one by using anonymous method and one by Lambda expression. I want to compare which one is taking less time.

How can I do this in VS express? (not only for delegate for methods also)

If it is Duplicate, please link it.

Thanks

**I tried Like This:**

```
        /** Start Date time**/
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        /********do the square of a number by using LAMBDA EXPRESSIONS********/
        returnSqr myDel = x => x * x;
        Console.WriteLine("By Lambda Expression Square of {0} is: {1}", a,myDel(a));
        /** Stop Date time**/
        DateTime stopTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan duration = stopTime - startTime;
        Console.WriteLine("Execution time 1:" + duration.Milliseconds);



        /** Start Date time**/            
        DateTime startTime2 = DateTime.Now;
        /*****do the square of a number by using ANONYMOUS EXPRESSIONS********/
        returnSqr myDel1 = delegate(int x) { return x * x;};
        Console.WriteLine("By Anonymous Method Square of  {0} is: {1}", a, myDel1(a));
        /** Stop Date time**/
        DateTime stopTime2 = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan duration2 = stopTime2 - startTime2;
        Console.WriteLine("Execution Time 2:" + duration.Milliseconds);
```

Output gives:

Execution time 1 : 0
Execution time 2 : 0

Why like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the stopwatch class.

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
// rest of the code
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Total time (ms): {0}", (long) sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: I tried(Edit my code with Stopwatch), Both giving same out put, I think execution time in too quick that not captured by milliseconds also.

Comment: Yep. Put some heavy loop between 'Stopwatch.StartNew' and 'sw.Stop' and monitor results.

Comment: ya its executing... thanx dude

Answer (score 4):

use StopWatch class to start a timer before the code is run and stop it after the code has ended. Do this for both code snippets and find out which takes mroe time.

This is not a perfect solution but it helps

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the [Scenario](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Scenario/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Home&version=3) class which supports simple begin/end usage, with optional logging via ETW.

From their Wiki:

> You can use the Scenario class to add performance instrumentation to an application (either .NET or native C++). The shortest description of a Scenario is "a named stopwatch that can log when you start and stop it".

Answer (score 0):

Just using the stopwatch class should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**Most likely, your code is executing more quickly than the maximum resolution of your timing device.** That's why it's reporting "0" milliseconds as the execution time for both pieces of code: the amount of time that has passed is undetectable. For some people, that might be enough to conclude it probably doesn't matter which way you do it.

**However, if it's important to get an accurate comparison of each method's speed, you could try running the code in a tight loop.** Essentially, *do* whatever it is you are *doing* about 100 or 1,000 or even a million times in a row, however many it takes to pass a sufficient amount of time that will register on your time-keeping device. Obviously, it won't take anywhere near that long to run the routine once or even several times in your final code, but at least it will give you an idea as to the *relative* speed of each option.

Comment: Ya I think the same, I will execute the same code with some loops and see the difference.